# Maya setAttr ed

Tags: maya, setattr

Sorry guys maybe the question is stupid or even I ask in a wrong way. But I'm totally new with Maya. So hope can get some help here. Thank you so much!
The question is:
I have a .ma file, and it has something like

setAttr ".ed[6474:6639]" 8053 8052 1 8053 8052 0 ...

1. what's the meaning of [6474:6639]? Is that the edge sequential number, from edge 6575 to 6639?
2. Does 8053 8052 8053 8052 mean 8053th point, and so on?
3. What is meaning of 1 and 0?

Thank you again!!

Comment: Sorry, but this site is about programming. What are you trying to do? It's very likely that you're tackling your problem the wrong way. You're asking about internals of Maya's file format. You don't even provide enough context for an answer. Also, just ask the question you want to ask, remove all that "sorry guys" stuff. Note that you can edit your question.

Comment: I second Andreas on that. Please make your question clear. Provide enough context, i.e. what led you to this problem, and some more information. Keep it professional. No questions are stupid.

Comment: @kartikg3 Well, I disagree, there are very stupid questions. :) But one should never feel stupid for not knowing something. Be proud even for having the courage to ask.

Comment: Andreas, very true. Agreed.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question:

1. `".ed[6474:6639]"` signifies the edges of the model from indices 6474 to 6639 in sequential order.
2. Yes. 8053 8052 8053 8052 mean the corresponding vertex indices that would have been set using a previous `setAttr` call. eg. `setAttr ".v[8011:9024]" 0.5 -0.5 0.5 ....`
3. `0` denotes "Hard" and `1` denotes "Smooth" edge.

You can find more information in the [setAttr docs here](http://download.autodesk.com/us/maya/2011help/CommandsPython/setAttr.html). On that page just look for `-type mesh`, and you'll find more information.

Hope that was useful.